# Inner Product of Probability Mass Vectors: Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability

I am looking for terminology and results around "inner product" of distributions. As an example, consider the vector representation $Bin(n, p)\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ of binomial distribution $$
Bin(n, p) = \begin{bmatrix}
p^n & {n \choose 1} p^{n-1} (1-p) & \ldots & {n \choose n} (1-p)^n
\end{bmatrix}$$

**Question:** Is there a formula/inequalities for the standard inner product $\langle Bin(n,p), Bin(n,q) \rangle$ in terms of $n$, $p$ and $q$? In particular, if $p-q = \varepsilon$, then is it true that $|\langle Bin(n,p), Bin(n,q) \rangle| \leq O(\frac{1 -\varepsilon}{\sqrt{n}})$?